# 01d 04h 19m 23s converting to decimal on google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, time, duration, converters, hour

I am trying to convert total time on phone to a decimal format. I have seen how to convert hours and minutes. I haven't found anything for Days.
=HOUR(A1)+MINUTE(A1)/60. This formula works. except for the day = 24 hours. if there is a 1. and if it is zero to ignore the number.

total time on phone 01d 04h 19m 23s how can I convert this to 28:19.23.

Thank You

Comment: What's the structure of your data look like in `A1`? Is it text values of `01d 04h 19m 23s`?

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(SUM(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(A1, " "), "\D+", )/
 {1, 24, 1440, 86400}), "[hh]:mm:ss"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

=sumproduct(left(Split(A1," "),2)/{1,24,24*60,24*60*60})

Then select the cell and Format>Number>more formats>custom number formatting, and paste this.